# If (arraylist contains "1" && string contains "1") print error

Tags: java, if-statement, arraylist, contains

Trying to create a group of up to 4 people ,however, people with the same ID can't be in the same group e.g "Tim ID1, Josh ID2, Ben ID3, George ID4" that would be a fine but "James ID2" cant join that group because Josh is already in it.

```
String person = request.getParameter("name") +" ID"+ request.getParameter("id");
people = new ArrayList();

if (people.size() >= 4){
    people.clear(); //Just to stop more than 4 persons in the group
}

for (int i = 0; i < people.size(); i++) {
    if (people.contains("1") && person.contains("1")){
        out.println("Error");
    } else if (people.contains("2") && person.contains("2")){
        out.println("Error");
    } else if (people.contains("3") && person.contains("3")){
        out.println("Error");
    } else if (people.contains("4") && person.contains("4")){
        out.println("Error");
    }
}

//If person does not have an id that is in the arraylist
people.add(person);
```

I cant understand why this method doesn't work, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You mean `persons` or `person`?

Comment: From what I see your people list is always of size 0. You should post the entire code. Btw, do you really use raw list ? new ArrayList(); What does people list contain?

Comment: Sorry I meant person, A simple version would be if tims id = x and x wasnt in the the array list then add tim to arraylist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < people.size(); i++)
```

in this for loop your condition `i<people.size()` will always be false because you have not inserted anything inside the `arrayList people`.

change your for loop to `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)` or something to true condition

Comment: changed to i <=4 because the group can only have 4 members, but this doesn't solve the main issue, if id is in array don't add person to arraylist

Comment: @Louis Dickinson  since you don't want the person with same id in same group then you have to create new arraylist (say List people1  = new  people1();) to add that person and next time when you add a new person then you have to check both the arraylist(people and people1) and this process will go on until you keep on adding new person.

Comment: @Louis Dickinson  post your full code that you have implemented

Comment: Thats not the only mistake in his code. You cant directly check a list entry for a substring. You need to fetch the object and check it individually. As i have mentioned in my answer.